# Page execution after cURL timed out

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

Can you please tell me what happens after multi cURL timed out (using `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`)? I need pages that I call with `curl_multi_exec` to be executed 100% but I do not want to wait for the results.

- CURLOPT_TIMEOUT is 1 sec
- Each page execution time is ~20 secs

I am using https://github.com/chuyskywalker/rolling-curl

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on the remote page that you are calling.  In most cases the server will completely execute the page that you call, but that may not always be true.  It is possible for the server to detect that the client closed the connection an terminate execution.

Comment: I am trying to call admin-ajax.php (default wp ajax page) on the same server.

Comment: Unless that script is explicitly checking to see if the client closed the connection (http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php), it will complete execution even after the client times out and disconnects.